# Can't post statuses longer than one word using Postman (Twitter API v1.1)

Tags: api, twitter, postman

i'm trying the twitter api v1.1 with Postman.

Calling https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json with status long one word works perfectly, but if i try more than one word it gave me error code 32 and text "Could not authenticate you."
i tried url encoding the status parameter, and trying with and without ' or "
Any help is very apreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your trials and errors. Please take a look at [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly